# How to define a DllImport declaration from c/c++ to c#

Tags: c#, struct, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

i want to use a c libary for my program in C#.
This libary contains a headerfile with functions in c, to control a camera.

Some of these functions in c, use a pointer called `*fg`
which points at a typedef called `Fg_Struct`
and finally this typedef is declared as `Typedef struct Fg_Struct_s Fg_Struct`

So now, i want to use these functions from the header file in my c# program.
I created a new class and imported these functions from the dll-libary
over the pinvoker-addon.
The pinvoker-addon created a new declaration of these functions 
(from unmanaged to managed).
Most of these new declared functions has a variable called
`Fg_Struct [] Fg`

Visual Studio shows me an error for "Fg_Struct is undefined" in C# programm.

---

For example, i can use the Fg_getLastErrorDiscripstion function to call the Error discription

**in C:**

fgrab_struct.h

```
typedef struct Fg_Struct_s Fg_Struct;
```

fgrab-prototyp.h

```
include "struct.h"
const char *const Fg_getLastErrorDescription(Fg_Struct *Fg);
```

main.cpp

```
Fg_Struct *fg = NULL;
fg = Fg_Init(DLLNAME, boardNr)
fprintf(stderr, "error in Fg_Init: %s\n", Fg_getLastErrorDescription(NULL));
```

**now i want to use it in c#:**

CAM_SISO.cs

```
[DllImport("fglib5.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static IntPtr Fg_getLastErrorDescription(Fg_Struct [] Fg);`
```

I'm really new in C# programming and researched in every topics with pinvoker 
but I couldn't find a right answer for me, how to declare or define Fg_Struct [] Fg to use the Fg_getLastErrorDiscription function in C#.

Comment: His DLL exports plain functions and standard layout types; this is not at all a duplicate of asking how to access a `declspec(dllexport)` class.

Comment: I think his question is specific to define the structure " Fg_Struct [] Fg", so may not be duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't ever actually look inside a `Fg_Struct`, only pass it to other functions in the DLL, then you can use `IntPtr` wherever the C header file has `Fg_Struct*`.

In addition to that, since C source code uses a pointer for any of: array, pass-by-reference parameter, output parameter, the automated p/invoke generator has to guess and will often produce wrong results, such as arrays where they don't belong.